# Nullity of an integral by integration by parts

Tags: integration

I have a question that seems really silly. I just want to reassure myself.
What could prevent this integral from being zero?
$$
\int_{R^d} \frac{f(x)}{\vert f(x)\vert}div(v)(x)dx
$$

We assume that the functions $f$ and the vector field $v$ are regular

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a reason you're worried about this integral being zero?

Comment: I'm just worried that the sign function isn't really constant and basically its derivative is a measure

Comment: To get the proper font and spacing for an operator like $\operatorname{div}$, use `\operatorname{div}`.

Answer (score 0):

Using integration by parts (and assuming appropriate regularity towards infinity), the integral equals

$$I = \int\limits_{\{f(x)=0\}\subset\Bbb{R}^d}\frac{-2\left(\nabla f \cdot v\right)}{\left|\nabla f\left(\{f(x)=0\}\right)\right|}\:d\sigma$$

where $d\sigma$ is the surface measure of the $(d-1)$ dimensional level space $f(x)=0$. In general this is not a quantity that is $0$